# Python setup.py with private repository on GitLab as dependency_links based on commit ID

Tags: python, git, dependencies, gitlab, setup.py

I am trying to install a private dependency (not something that Python could find on PyPI).

I have added to the file `setup.py` this (as explained here: https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html#packages-not-on-pypi):

```py
dependency_links = [
        'https://gitlab.com/<PRIVATE_ORG>/<PRIVATE_REPO>.git@<COMMIT_ID>'
      ]
```

On that official documentation they don't really explain in details what's the format of that URL, however using a `<COMMIT_ID` after the `@` sounds reasonable (as it's done in a variety of other languages and dependency management tools).

When executing the command `python setup.py install` then I see in the logs/output this:

```
Reading https://gitlab.com/<PRIVATE_ORG>/<PRIVATE_REPO>.git@<COMMIT_ID>
```

but then I don't see that package being actually installed as I can see from the logs/output for other dependencies.

I know there is a valid GitLab access token setup for my `git` command, because I've run this:

```sh
git config \
      --global \
      url."https://<ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME>:<ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE>@gitlab.com".insteadOf \
      "https://gitlab.com"
```

and I can see it when checking the `git` config with:

```sh
git config --list | grep gitlab
url.https://<ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME>:<ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE>@gitlab.com.insteadof=https://gitlab.com
```

- Is Python using the `git` command when running `setup.py`?
- How can I specify a private GitLab dependency inside a Python `setup.py` file? **It should be based on a commit ID rather than a package version**
- What's wrong with the above?
- I have also the feeling this may be running differently when using `pip install` and targeting `setup.py` instead of running `python setup.py install`, is there a unique way of making this work with both flavors of Python installations? I am asking this because when fiddling with `dependency_links` I was trying various things like `git+ssh` instead of `https` and other variations, all of them failing to install that private repository with various log/outputs saying that repository was not found.

**Edit**

I've avoided `dependency_links` because it seems deprecated, so I used the solution proposed in the answer as:

```
install_requires=[
    ...
    "mylibraryname @ git+https://<ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME>:<ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE>@gitlab.com/<PRIVATE_ORG>/<PRIVATE_REPO>.git@<COMMIT_ID>",
    ...
],
```

However when executing `python setup.py install --record installed_files.txt`, then the installation **fails** with this message:

```
Searching for mylibraryname@ git+https://<ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME>:<ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE>@gitlab.com/<PRIVATE_ORG>/<PRIVATE_REPO>.git@<COMMIT_ID>
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/mylibraryname/
Couldn't find index page for 'mylibraryname' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/
No local packages or working download links found for mylibraryname@ git+https://<ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME>:<ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE>@gitlab.com/<PRIVATE_ORG>/<PRIVATE_REPO>.git@<COMMIT_ID>
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('mylibraryname@ git+https://<ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME>:<ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE>@gitlab.com/<PRIVATE_ORG>/<PRIVATE_REPO>.git@<COMMIT_ID>')
```

So I tried to use `pip install .` assuming there is a `setup.py` file in the current directory, this worked:

```
Collecting mylibraryname@ git+https://<ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME>:<ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE>@gitlab.com/<PRIVATE_ORG>/<PRIVATE_REPO>.git@<COMMIT_ID> from git+https://<ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME>:****@gitlab.com/<PRIVATE_ORG>/<PRIVATE_REPO>.git@<COMMIT_ID> (from <MY_LIBRARY_WITH_SETUP_PY>==<MY_LIBRARY_VERSION>)
  Cloning https://<ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME>:****@gitlab.com/<PRIVATE_ORG>/<PRIVATE_REPO>.git (to revision <COMMIT_ID>) to /tmp/pip-install-bakazwe2/mylibraryname
  Running command git clone -q https://<ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME>:sYzRKNsYAnv5GtS6zLZj@gitlab.com/<PRIVATE_ORG>/<PRIVATE_REPO>.git /tmp/pip-install-bakazwe2/mylibraryname
```

This solution seems to **work only when using `pip install .` in a directory containing `setup.py`**. This does not work with `python setup.py install --record installed_files.txt`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/ is quite old and outdated. Its sources was [last updated](https://github.com/storborg/python-packaging/commits/master) at Dec 29, 2016 and most parts of it were not updated since 2012. Python packaging landscape changed significantly since that times. The new docs are at https://packaging.python.org/

`dependency_links` were declared obsolete and finally [removed](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi) in `pip` 19.0. The replacement for it is `install_requires` with special syntax (supported since `pip` 19.1):

```
install_requires=[
    'package_name @ git+https://gitlab.com/<PRIVATE_ORG>/<PRIVATE_REPO>.git@<COMMIT_ID>'
]
```

See https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references

This requires `pip install` including `pip install .` and doesn't work with `python setup.py install`.

Comment: Thanks that worked only when using `pip install .`, I would like to accept this answer could you just please mention the caveat between `pip install .` and `python setup.py install --record installed_files.txt`, perhaps why it fails with the 2nd. Thanks again

Comment: For some reason when I update the commit ID to a new value, then `pip` says `Requirement already satisfied`. I have to manually first `pip uninstall -y package_name` to be sure that `pip` then pulls the version with the expected commit ID.

Comment: what if I want to specify the master branch commit?

Comment: @LukAron Please be more specific — do you want to specify the `master` branch (different commits every time `pip install` is using) or exactly one commit (not related to branch)?

Comment: @phd the commit that the master branch is pointing to when the `pip install` run

Comment: @LukAron Just use `@master`: `install_requires=[ 'package_name @ git+https://gitlab.com/<PRIVATE_ORG>/<PRIVATE_REPO>.git@master' ]`

Comment: @phd thanks so much,   what if I want a dev branch named "dev". instead of the "master" branch?    sorry for asking but I really didnt find any documentation of this

Comment: found it ,  https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git

Answer (score 0):

I've read multiple answers, but only this one worked for me (using `pip 20.2.3` and [Gitlab Pypi](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/) feature):

```sh
pip3 install --extra-index-url https://__token__:my_personal_token@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/347/packages/pypi/simple .
```

My `setup.py` looked like:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='whatever_production_scripts',
      version='0.0.1',
      description='Whatever production scripts',
      url='https://gitlab.com/user/whatever',
      author='Me Myself',
      author_email='user@whatever.com',
      license='All rights reserved',
      scripts=[
          'whatever_production_scripts/production/insomnia.py',
          'whatever_production_scripts/production/rdsmaintenance.py',
          'whatever_production_scripts/production/changeinstancetype.py',
      ],
      packages=[
          'whatever_production_scripts',
          'whatever_production_scripts.production',
      ],
      classifiers=[
          "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
          "Intended Audience :: System Administrators",
          "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
          "Topic :: Internet",
          "Topic :: System :: Systems Administration",
          "Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only"
      ],
      install_requires=[
          'privatepackage1>=0.1',
          'publicpackage1>=7',
          'publicpackage2>=2'
      ],
      zip_safe=False)
```